# PHPUnit best practice for fixation of value returned by protected method?

Tags: php, phpunit

consider the following code as PHP-style pseudo code to get my point across.

```
class C extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function m1()
  {
    $v = $this->m2();

    if($v == "x")
    {
      throw new Exception();
    }
  }

  protected function m2()
  {
    [...];

    return $v;
  }
}
```

now I want to add a test that asserts that an Exception is thrown if m2() returns "x".

How can I simulate that?

I thought about using Reflection to redefine the method during runtime, but it seems that Reflection doesn't offer such a functionality and I would have to resort to experimental extensions like classkit or runkit. Would that be the way to go?

In this case I could extend the class and redefine m2() but where would I put that derived class then? In the same file as the test?

The latter solution wouldn't work anymore if I would choose m2 to be private.

I'm quite sure that there is a best practice to deal with this situation.

Comment: Just put your class in a state where m2 raise an exception?

Comment: this would just shift the need to influence object internals from m1 to m2, as m2 gets information from file_get_contents() and I cannot influence its outcome.

Answer (score 4):

Ether I'm completely off on what you are trying to do here or you are doing something that confuses me greatly.

To me is seems that you are asking for is that you want to check that **your test method throws an exception**.

> class C extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

Why would you want to test your test method?

---

#### I'm going to assume that that is the real class and not your test

In that case I always strongly argue for just testing it as if the protected method would be inline in the public method.

You want to test the **external behavior** of your class. Not the implementation. The protected method is and implementation detail that your *test* shouldn't care about. That would mean that you would have to change your test when you change that protected method.

And from there on out:

```
class CTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

     public function testM1NormalBehavior() {

     }

     /**
      * @expectedException YourException
      */
     public function testM1ThrowsExceptionWhenM2ConditionsAreMet() {
         $c = new C('set_Up_In_A_Way_That_Makes_M2_Return_X');
         $c->m1();
     }

}
```

Comment: +1 for that $c = new C('set_Up_In_A_Way_That_Makes_M2_Return_X');

Comment: @Alfwed ;) Yeah. But the main point I was trying to make with that joke is: "if you are not able to set up C in a way that makes M2 return X then you can't properly test it. It might be global state. If it's a random generator or something it would have ether to be factored out or "hacked". But those hackisch solutions depend on the exact usecase so there was not much chance of answering that ;)

Comment: I totally agree with you. That was also the point of my comment. If he can't make set up the class to throw an exception then we can't help him with the code sample provided. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a partial mock of `C` to force `m2()` to return `"x"`. I'll assume that the `extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` was accidental and that `C` is actually the class under test and not the unit test itself.

```
class CTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /**
     * @expectedException Exception
     */
    function testM1ThrowsExceptionWhenM2ReturnsX() {
        $c = $this->getMock('C', array('m2'));
        $c->expects($this->once())->method('m2')->will($this->returnValue('x'));
        $c->m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: While it leaves m2 completely untested it can be a good way to "get started" but shouldn't (imho) not be used as a default approach to testing/writing classes. +1 though :)

Comment: Agreed on the general case. I use partial mocking when I need to test methods that depend on external systems. Instead of setting up a web service that allows me to make it timeout on the next call, I extract the call to the web service to a separate method and mock that method to do what I want. Just make sure you have some end-to-end integration/system tests as well.